# stripe account.updated webhook is making user data come back as null

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

so I just made my first stripe webhook and am really happy with it. Pretty much all it does is update our db and add the correct 'charges_enabled' field from the stripe user. It also currently adds the entire stripe account into the db, but that will get removed before production. However, after playing around with it for a little bit I realized when this webhook fires, it never has any of the user's information, such as name, email or address. Before we found out about webhooks we used to manually check the stripe account with this code below:

```
  await stripe?.accounts.retrieve(user?.stripeID))
```

This code would always return the account object with the submitted user information.

Some insight into our project, we are using react native and using stripe connect express. We pretty much configured it exactly how they describe in the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide). When a user signs up to become a host, they get an account link from stripe and they go to the browser to sign up. Like I said before when we manually check this status after they submitted the form on the website, we were getting everything back, but now with the webhook we get everything, except the data.object.business_profile object has a lot of null information. This is not desired because it also updates the stripe account to having no name, or no email address. I have absolutely no idea why this might be happening and was wondering what could be going on.

EDIT: I realized now, that when it fires, it actually overwrites this information from the account. For example, if I go to the stripe dashboard and turn off the webhook and make a new host. Everything is shown in the dashboard, name, email,etc, but then if I turn on the webhook and edit one of the fields(example name) it changes all the personal(data.object.business_profile) information to null. This is just the account coming back from stripe, so I am not sure why this information is null, even though I am very clearly setting it in the browser.

It also is not deleting all the information from the account, because it still has the bank account information and some other personal stuff like date of birth.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the type of account you're using? Which attributes specifically are you trying to inspect? Note that details about the `company` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-company)) and `individual` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-individual)) are both marked as "Custom Only". These fields are not made available to you for Express or Standard accounts, as those details are collected and manage by Stripe on your behalf. It's expected that those are not included in account retrievals or webhook event payloads.